# Flutter. Drag a Draggable item onto another Draggable item

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the below board. There is an overlay (`Stack`) of 2 x 10 widgets, some transparent ones which are `DragTargets` and above them, the same width and height there are ones which are `Draggable`. The `Draggable` ones are the ones containing the images.

[image]

The problem that I'm facing is that the `onWillAccept` and `onAccept` methods from the ones below, are not called while I drag the ones above. I'm guessing because there are widgets overlaying them.

I've switched the widgets around, having the `DragTargets` overlay-ing the `Draggable` ones but now I can't drag them as they're below other widgets.

All examples of drag-and-drops are dragging an item from a place and placing it on another, one draggable, one dragTarget. I require a widget (or a zone on the screen) to be both draggable and a dragTarget. How could I accomplish this?

Here's the layout

```
          Align(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("images/user_board.jpg"),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                ),
              ),
              height: _userBoardH,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      height: _tileH,
                      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: _buildSlots(ScreenBoard.FIRST_ROW),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: _buildTiles(ScreenBoard.FIRST_ROW),
                        ),
                      ])),
                  Container(
                      height: _tileH,
                      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: _buildSlots(ScreenBoard.SECOND_ROW),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: _buildTiles(ScreenBoard.SECOND_ROW),
                        ),
                      ])),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          ),
```

Cheers.

**EDIT**

Solved it by following Patrick's suggestion. Here's the solution:

```
Widget _buildTile(Tile widget) {
  return DragTarget<Map>(
    builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
      return Container(
        child: Draggable<Map>(
          child: _getTile(widget),
          feedback: _getTile(widget),
          childWhenDragging: Container(
            width: widget._dimenW,
            height: widget._dimenH,
          ),
          data: {
            Tile.DATA_TILE_ROW_TYPE: widget._rowType,
            Tile.DATA_TILE_ROW_POS: widget._rowPosition,
            Tile.DATA_TILE_ID: widget._tileId,
          },
        ),
      );
    },
    onWillAccept: (data) {
      UDebug.log("onWillAccept");
      return false;
    },
    onAccept: (data) {
      UDebug.log("onAccept");
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap it in a Container() widget and put the image in a BoxDecoration() and use the child: property to hold your Draggable().

This won't obstruct your pointer events.

Comment: I'm way too tired to even try to figure out what you just said. Could you do with a simple, even pseudo-code, example ?

Comment: What exactly should I wrap in a container?