# Draggable and DragTarget in one

Tags: flutter

How can you make a "cell" both Draggable and a DragTarget, like on a chess board?

In this sample code `onWillAccept` is never hit:

```
                DragTarget<String>(
                  builder: (
                      BuildContext context,
                      List<dynamic> accepted,
                      List<dynamic> rejected,
                      ) {
                    return Draggable(
                      data: "data",
                      childWhenDragging: Container(),
                      feedback: Text("I am dragging"),
                      child: Text("Drag me"),
                    );
                  },
                  onWillAccept: (data) {
                    return true;
                  },
                  onAccept: (data) {},
                )
```

**Update**
Found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291327/flutter-drag-a-draggable-item-onto-another-draggable-item) one -
having DragTarget build the Draggable is the way to go. You just need to wrap the Draggable in a Container.